# associative arrays awk vs python

Tags: python, awk, associative-array

I am using associative arrays in awk in order to perform calculations from values in a dataset. I wonder how to perform exactly the same operations in Python.

> Input
>   Key1;cr;10
>   Key1;db;5
>   Key2;cr;5
>   Key2;db;7
>   Key2;cr;9
>   Key2;cr;12
>   Key3;db;3

```
awk -F";" '{a[$1]+=$2=="cr"?$3:$3*-1}END{for(i in a){print i FS a[i]}}' input
```

> Output
>   Key1;5
>   Key2;19
>   Key3;9

Comment: could you give your actual algorithm than a non-working awk command?

Comment: An expert in python may not know awk and anyone would be confused by the cryptic statement `a[$1]+=$2=="cr"?$3:$3*-1`. Can't you add some parentheses to clarify (and make it portable - as written that code will produce syntax errors from some awks) and an explanation of what the awk code is doing? You'd stand a better chance of getting a python expert to consider helping you if you did.

Comment: The `awk` was simply missing a close parenthesis (and is still inscrutable).  Basically, though, it adds `cr` (credit) values and subtracts `db` (debit) values from the running total for each different key.

Comment: How do you get Key3 to sum to 9?

Comment: My main point was really just that posting a program in language X with no explanation of it and asking how to write it in language Y is a bad idea because it requires someone who knows both languages well to answer it when all you should really NEED to get a script in language Y is someone who knows language Y. The convoluted ternary expression didn't help though!

Answer (score 1):

Python 2:

```
data = '''Key1;cr;10
Key1;db;5
Key2;cr;5
Key2;db;7
Key2;cr;9
Key2;cr;12
Key3;db;3
'''

results = {}

for line in data.splitlines():

    fields = line.split(';')

    if fields[0] not in results:
        results[fields[0]] = 0

    if fields[1] == 'cr':
        results[fields[0]] += int(fields[2])
    else:
        results[fields[0]] -= int(fields[2])

#--- END ---

for key in sorted(results.keys()):
    print '%s;%s' % (key, results[key])
```

---

EDIT:

By the way:

```
a[$1]+=$2=="cr"?$3:$3*-1
```

can be done in Python (pseudocode)

```
a[$1] += ( $3 if $2=="cr" else $3*-1 )
```